# How to catch a no parse exception from the read function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, exception, io

In my Haskell program, I want to read in a value given by the user using the `getLine` function.  I then want to use the `read` function to convert this value from a string to the appropriate Haskell type.  How can I catch parse errors thrown by the `read` function and ask the user to reenter the value?

Am I right in thinking that this is not an "IO Error" because it is not an error caused by the IO system not functioning correctly?  It is a semantic error, so I can't use IO error handling mechanisms?

Comment: In upcoming GHC 7.6, there will be `Text.Read.readEither :: Read a => String -> Either String a` and `Text.Read.readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't want to. You want to use [reads](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.0.0.0/doc/html/Text-Read.html#v%3Areads) instead, possibly like that:

```
maybeRead = fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads
```

(though you might want to error out if the second element of the tuple is not `""`, that is, if there's a remaining string, too)

The *reason* why you want to use reads instead of catching `error` exceptions is that exceptions in pure code are evil, because it's *very* easy to attempt to catch them in the wrong place: Note that they only fly when they are forced, not before. Locating where that is can be a non-trivial exercise. That's (one of the reasons) why Haskell programmers like to keep their code total, that is, terminating and exception-free.

You might want to have a look at a proper parsing framework (e.g. [parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec)) and [haskeline](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline), too.

Comment: `maybeRead` is in the `utility-ht` and `applicative-extras` packages on hackage (among others), and it is proposed for inclusion in base.   I'm not sure of the status of that proposal.

Answer (score 15):

There are `readMaybe` and `readEither` that satisfy your expectation. You find this functions in `Text.Read` package.

Answer (score 8):

This is an addendum to @barsoap's answer more than anything else.

Haskell exceptions may be thrown anywhere, including in pure code, but they may only be caught from within the IO monad.  In order to catch exceptions thrown by pure code, you need to use a `catch` or `try` on the IO statement that would force the pure code to be evaluated.

```
str2Int :: String -> Int -- shortcut so I don't need to add type annotations everywhere
str2Int = read

main = do
  print (str2Int "3") -- ok
  -- print (str2Int "a") -- raises exception
  eVal <- try (print (str2Int "a")) :: IO (Either SomeException ())
  case eVal of
    Left e -> do -- couldn't parse input, try again
    Right n -> do -- could parse the number, go ahead
```

You should use something more specific than `SomeException` because that will catch anything.  In the above code, the `try` will return a `Left exception` if `read` can't parse the string, but it will also return a `Left exception` if there's an IO error when trying to print the value, or any number of other things that could possibly go wrong (out of memory, etc.).

Now, here's why exceptions from pure code are evil.  What if the IO code doesn't actually force the result to be evaluated?

```
main2 = do
  inputStr <- getLine
  let data = [0,1,read inputStr] :: [Int]
  eVal <- try (print (head data)) :: IO (Either SomeException ())
  case eVal of
    Right () -> do -- No exception thrown, so the user entered a number ?!
    Left e   -> do -- got an exception, probably couldn't read user input
```

If you run this, you'll find that you always end up in the `Right` branch of the case statement, no matter what the user entered.  This is because the IO action passed to `try` doesn't ever try to `read` the entered string.  It prints the first value of the list `data`, which is constant, and never touches the tail of the list.  So in the first branch of the case statement, the coder thinks the data is evaluated but it isn't, and `read` may still throw an exception.

`read` is meant for unserializing data, not parsing user-entered input.  Use `reads`, or switch to a real parser combinator library.  I like [uu-parsinglib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib), but [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.1), [polyparse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/polyparse), and many others are good too.  You'll very likely need the extra power before long anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an improved `maybeRead` which allows only for trailing whitespaces, but nothing else:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Char

maybeRead2 :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead2 = fmap fst . listToMaybe . filter (null . dropWhile isSpace . snd) . reads
```

Comment: `null . dropWhile isSpace` is just `all isSpace`, no?