# haskell: RPN Calculator

Tags: list, haskell, console

I want to develop a sort of stack managing system. The list starts by being empty [] and a user can input numbers and they will be added to the list, as well as binary operations, which will take two first numbers from a list and perform the operation and then put it back on the list. EG:

```
[] : 3
[3] : 4
[4,3] : +
[7] : c
[] : 123
[123] : 3
[3,123] : *
[369] :
```

I cannot figure out how to process input from the console. I have this broken code:

```
import System.Environment   
import System.Directory  
import System.IO  
import Data.List  

stack = []

add1 :: [Int] -> [Int]
add1 [] = []
add1 [x] = [x]
add1 [x,y] = [(x+y)]
add1 x:(y:xs) = (x+y) : (xs : []) 

--sub :: [Int] -> [Int]
--sub [] = []
--sub x:(y:xs) = (x-y) : xs 

--mul :: [Int] -> [Int]
--mul [] = []
--mul x:(y:xs) = (x*y) : xs 

--div :: [Int] -> [Int]
--div [] = []
--div x:(y:xs) = (x/y) : xs 

c :: [Int] -> [Int]
c = []

push :: [Int] -> a -> [Int]
push [] a = [a]
push (x:xs) a = a : (x:xs)

dispatch :: [(String, Int -> IO ())]
dispatch =  [ ("+", add)
       --     , ("-", sub)
       --     , ("*", mul)
       --     , ("/", div)
            ]

xcl = do
    print stack
    answer <- readLine
```

But I don't even know if I'm heading in the right direction. Any help will be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *are* on the right path; lets take a look at some changes to your code I would suggest.

Your `add1` function is quite close, but you've got two small problems - the first is the pattern match you provide: to be syntactically correct, you need the whole match to be inside the parentheses.  The second is the second cons (colon).  cons has a type of `a -> [a] -> [a]`, so it works perfectly with `(x+y)` as the first parameter; however, since `xs` has type `[Int]` already, you don't need to supply `: []`.

```
add1 (x:y:xs) = (x+y) : xs
```

Next, because you are dealing entirely with `Int`s and lists of `Int`s, using some type `a` does not make sense in this context.

```
push :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
```

Finally, your workhorse function.  Because of the lack of loop constructs in Haskell, the way to do a user input loop (also known an [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL)) is through recursion.  Because of this, it would make some sense to accept a parameter.  Let's make that your `[Int]` stack.  The function to read one line from stdin as a string is `getLine`, which has type `IO String`.  Finally, you actually have to handle that input.  For simplicity, I've just included that logic in a `case` statement in `xcl`, but it could as well have been done using `dispatch` or a similar function (In fact, if your RPN calculater becomes more complicated, this would have its merits).  The action for each case should recurse into your xcl "loop" with a modified stack.  When you quit, it should just exit - which is a good use of `return`.

```
xcl :: [Int] -> IO ()
xcl st = do
    print st
    answer <- getLine
    case answer of
      "q" -> return ()
      "c" -> xcl ([] ::[Int])
      "+" -> xcl $ add1 st
      x -> xcl $ push st $ read x
```

In fact, you could take this one step further and protect against exceptions - what will happen when the user passes in some non-function, non-number string?  The code above will fail, with a "no parse" exception.  The best way around that is to use `reads` in place of `read`, as is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121371/how-to-catch-a-no-parse-exception-from-the-read-function-in-haskell/5121537#5121537).  `reads` returns either a list with a single entry - a tuple containing a parsed number and a remaining string, or an empty list (indicating a failed read).  For example:

```
      x -> case (reads x) of
        [(num,_)] -> xcl $ push st num
        _ -> xcl st
```

Answer (score 2):

```
xcl stack = do
    print stack
    answer <- getLine
    case lookup answer dispatch of
        Just function -> -- we have a function, apply it to the top of the stack
        Nothing -> -- if we have a number, parse it and push it onto the stack
                   -- if not, issue an error
```

1. `stack` cannot be a top level constant, because we will want to manipulate it. So we make it a parameter to `xcl` instead.
2. Use `getLine` to read a line of text, because we don't know whether we want to interpret it as an operator name or as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://learnyouahaskell.com/functionally-solving-problems#reverse-polish-notation-calculator . It may be helpfull.