# no parse exception

Tags: haskell

I am trying to cach exception caused by read function:

```
run :: CurrentData -> IO ()
run current = do
{
    x <- (getCommandFromUser) `E.catch` handler;
    updated <- executeCommand x current;
    run updated;    
} where handler :: E.IOException -> IO Command
    handler e = do putStrLn "wrong command format" >> return (DoNothing);
```

In this code function getCommandfrom user gets some string from user and then tries to read some data from this string using "read" function

If read fails there is exception thrown:

```
*** Exception : prelude.read : no parse
```

and program exits...
I can't catch this exception - what is type of this exception???

I tried also E.SomeException instead of E.IOException...

E is from import Control.Exception As E

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to catch a no parse exception from the read function in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121371/how-to-catch-a-no-parse-exception-from-the-read-function-in-haskell)

Comment: No that doesn't help me I wanna catch this exception...

Comment: Did you see the second answer? It shows how to catch it using `try`, however I strongly recommend considering the pure approach using `reads` and `Maybe`.

Answer (score 1):

"what is type of this exception?" The type is `ErrorCall`, also available from `Control.Exception`. An `ErrorCall` is what is thrown when the `error` function is called.
Just change the type of `handler` and it will work. A last resort to get things working is to catch `E.SomeException`, but that's almost always the wrong thing to do.