# How do I catch read exceptions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, try-catch

In the following Haskell code:

```
data Cmd =  
    CmdExit |  
    CmdOther  
    deriving (Read, Show)

guiString2Cmd s =  
    (return (read s :: Cmd)) `catch` \(e :: SomeException) -> return CmdExit
```

If I do:

```
guiString2Cmd "CmdOther"
```

it all works fine. However if I do:

```
guiString2Cmd "some wrong string"
```

the code crashes instead of evaluating to CmdExit.

How can I make the code handle the exception instead of crashing?

Comment: Using reads might be a better idea actually...

Comment: Yes, the best way to handle a pure exception is to not generate it in the first place.

Comment: For the record, exceptions (including those thrown by `read`) can only be caught in the IO monad, using functions provided in `Control.Exception`.  I won't go into further detail because `reads` is a better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to catch a no parse exception from the read function in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121371/how-to-catch-a-no-parse-exception-from-the-read-function-in-haskell)

Comment: Of course, the proper way is to avoid the exception in the first place. But if you _have_ to, you need to force the exception to occur when it still can be caught by forcing the evaluation of the expression, often using `Control.Exception.evaluate foo` or `return $! foo` instead of `return foo` does the trick, sometimes a deeper evaluation is necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `reads` function, which is total, and wrap the failure case as a `Maybe`, like so:

> ```
> maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
> maybeRead s = case reads s of
>     [(x, "")] -> Just x
>     _         -> Nothing
> ```

`maybeRead` is quite a versatile way to do safe parsing.

Comment: This function is available as [`Text.Read.readMaybe`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) in recent versions of `base`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to simply use *reads* instead.

Answer (score 2):

There exists an idiom of reading inside a monad:

```
readM :: (Monad m, Read a) => String -> m a
readM s | [x] <- [x | (x, "") <- reads s] = return x
        -- or @[x] <- [x | (x, _) <- reads s] = return x@
        -- to allow the garbage at the end of parsed string
        | otherwise = fail $ "Failed to parse: \"" ++ s ++ "\""
```

it's unsafe for the `IO` monad:

```
> readM "CmdOther" :: IO Cmd
CmdOther
> readM "Cmd?Other" :: IO Cmd
*** Exception: user error (Failed to parse: "Cmd?Other")
```

because `fail` throws an `IOError` exception in the case of `IO`, which, however, can be handled:

```
*Main> (readM "Cmd?Other" :: IO Cmd) `catch` const (return CmdOther)
CmdOther
```

And safe in the case of `Maybe` monad:

```
> readM "CmdOther" :: Maybe Cmd
Just CmdOther
> readM "Cmd?Other" :: Maybe Cmd
Nothing
```

because `fail` is `const Nothing` in this case.

Anyway, if you want a total function `guiString2Cmd` with a signature `String -> Cmd` you can write it just like `readM`:

```
guiString2Cmd :: String -> Cmd
guiString2Cmd s | [x] <- [x | (x, "") <- reads s] = x
                | otherwise = CmdExit
```

and then:

```
> guiString2Cmd "CmdOther"
CmdOther
> guiString2Cmd "Cmd?Other"
CmdExit
```

---

Slightly more generic approach.

For `*` kinds:

```
class Failable0 t where
  fail0 :: t

readG0 :: (Failable0 t, Read t) => String -> t
readG0 s | [x] <- [x | (x, "") <- reads s] = x
         | otherwise = fail0
```

then:

```
instance Failable0 Cmd where
  fail0 = CmdExit
```

For `* -> *` kinds:

```
class Failable f where
  fail :: String -> f a

class Functor f => Pointed f where
  pure :: a -> f a

readG :: (Failable f, Pointed f, Read a) => String -> f a
readG s | [x] <- [x | (x, "") <- reads s] = pure x
        | otherwise = fail $ "Failed to parse: \"" ++ s ++ "\""
```

Comment: `fail` isn't `error` in the case of `IO`, it throws an `IOError` exception. Compare `fail "oh no!" \`catch\` (\e -> print (e :: IOError))` with `error "oh no!" \`catch\` (\e -> print (e :: IOError))`

Comment: @benmachine right, ``fail "?" `catch` const (return "!")`` => `"!"` and ``error "?" `catch` const (return "!")`` => `*** Exception: ?`. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend using [`readMay`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/safe/0.3.3/doc/html/Safe.html) from the `safe` package:

```
readMay :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
```

Then you can either pattern-match on the 'Maybe a' result, use 'maybe', or even use the 'Maybe' monad to handle the result.