# haskell case that calls a function

Tags: haskell, error-handling, functional-programming

I have been at this for a long time, I cant figure out whats wrong
Haskell just makes me feel so dumb

```
data Operation
    = Nth Integer


fib :: (Integral i, Integral j) => i -> j

fib   n | n == 0         = 1
        | n == 1         = 1
        | n == 2         = 1
        | n == 3         = 1        
        | otherwise = (fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))* fib(n-3) `div` fib(n-4)
main = do
command <- getLine
case command of
    Nth op -> show $ fib op
    Nothing -> "Invalid operation"
```

So when the user inputs Nth 9, the fib function needs to get called with n=9 and give the output to the user. I feel like my case control structure is appropriate, but I cant get it to work at all!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are almost complete.
use `deriving (Read)` for reading `String` as `Operation`.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Deriving

If you want to handle read error, see [How to catch a no parse exception from the read function in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121371/how-to-catch-a-no-parse-exception-from-the-read-function-in-haskell)

```
data Operation = Nth Integer deriving (Read)

fib :: (Integral i, Integral j) => i -> j

fib   n | n == 0         = 1
        | n == 1         = 1
        | n == 2         = 1
        | n == 3         = 1
        | otherwise = (fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))* fib(n-3) `div` fib(n-4)
main = do
  command <- getLine
  print $ case read command of
    Nth op -> fib op
```

Comment: That worked great for me...Is there anyways to output the value without "". If I get the output as "50"..I only want to print 50 in the terminal!

Comment: is it possible for me to store values obtained in fib during recursion in a list, using something other than a map function, so that I can carry out list operations

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what you wan't. Maybe you should create another question in Stackoverflow.